# Bootstrap Modal Remote Source Error Handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We are using `Bootstrap Modal window` to display some html that is loaded via a remote source.  We're doing this via the recommended way in the `Bootstrap` docs, by using the option `remote` and passing it a `url`.  (As described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

For example:

```
$('#id').modal({remote:'index.html'});
```

My question: Is it possible to handle an error in the case that index.html is not available?

I don't see any answer in the documentation.

I know this should rarely happen, however if someone has a slow or spotty connection, I'd rather show them an error than to just hang with an empty modal.

Comment: I gave a 1+ but I'm also going to add that it seems like a low chance that a single file will preform that poorly when the rest of the files aren't — in other words, your app/page will probably be problematic in other areas, assuming this asset is loaded from the same server/domain situation.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I agree.  We noticed this issue specifically on mobile -- which for obvious reasons can drop connections as coverage isn't always perfect.  When this happens our whole app is frozen as it doesn't have any conditions (as far as I can tell) for errors / timeouts.  You just get the dark backdrop covering the page -- until you do a hard reset.

Comment: Thank you for posting the question!  Especially while testing, it is much more helpful to see an error rather than wonder why the modal is blank or it still shows the content from the last load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to implement a Global Ajax Error Handler in your app, this will attach to every Ajax request that is performed, implementation would look something like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
  //Since this handler is attach to all ajax requests we can differentiate by the settings used to build the request
  if ( settings.url == "index.html" ) {
    //Handle error
  }
});
```

You can read more about Global Ajax Handlers [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Comment: I like updating the modal code rather than hard-coding all the different remote url's that could be loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the Github repo ( [/js/modal.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js) ) contains this fragment in the modal plugin definition:

```
…
if (this.options.remote) this.$element.load(this.options.remote)
…
```

Which indicates that no callback is used, the result of the request is directly assigned to the dom element being worked on.

From the docs [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data.

Later in the doc there is a code snippt that describes how to detect a failure with `load`:

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

It seems the Twitter team opted to *not* handle the error.

Maybe it's time to start an issue, it seems like a "mobile first" library would want to handle this kind of thing gracefully ;-) https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap v3.3.7 , here is the solution I came up with based on Mark Fox's answer .  Just find the " .load " section in your bootstrap js file, and make it look like this :

```
 if (this.options.remote) {
  this.$element
    .find('.modal-content')
    .load(this.options.remote, $.proxy(function (response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == 'error') {
        this.$element.find('.modal-content').html('<h1>Error</h1>'+response);
      }
      this.$element.trigger('loaded.bs.modal');
    }, this))
}
```

Substitute your own error message of course or whatever other code you need.